# Meteor server only variables/security keys

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

I have a page which takes only one input from the user: `passcode`

Now I want to verify this entered `passcode` and then redirect the user to the next page (let's say the order page). For security I would like to know if the user entered the `passcode` and came to the order page or just typed the URL in the address bar.

For example:

```
// Client code
Template.Home.events({
  'click #btnGoToOrderForm' : function() {
    var passcode = $('#inptPasscode').val();
    if ( passcode ) {
      Meteor.call('cehckPasscode', passcode, function(error, result) {
        if ( result == true ) {
          Router.go('order');
        }
      });
    }
  }
});


// Server code
Meteor.methods({
  'checkPasscode' : function(passcode) {
    console.log(passcode);
    if ( passcode == 'welcome' ) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="inptPasscode" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the passcode...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="btnGoToOrderForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="password">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value to the Session - but still people could modify the session and break your 'security'.

I would recommend going with HTTP authentication on that specific URL.

https://github.com/Jabbslad/basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like a bcrypt library to generate a salted hash before passing it between client/server:

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/npm-bcrypt

The doc for the package is completely missing, but it is actually the same as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt